# Regex: how to find string between separator (or not)

Tags: regex

I don't find a good regular expression for my problem.

I can have these strings:

- Lastname^Firstname^MiddleName^Prefix^Suffix
- Lastname^Firstname^^^
- Lastname^Firstname

I search a regex to find just the Lastname.
And another regex to find just the Firstname.

I have tried `[a-zA-Z'' -]{1,}`
and `(?<=\^)(.*?)(?=\^)` but I have no regular expression which matches all my cases.

Lastname regex, must return the string before the first character '^'.
Firstname regex must return the string after the first character '^' and stop at the end of the string or at the next character '^'.

For the moment I haven't need to retrieve the MiddleName, Prefix and Suffix.

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: @bashophil I would guess PHP, not sure though ...

Answer (score 1):

You can get Lastname  and Firstname with:

```
^([^^]+)\^([^^]+)
```

per this [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/fM9wQ8)

Note that the first `^` is the beginning anchor, the `^` after the `[` means "not" and the other `^`s are literals. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The regular expression you need could be:

```
/\d+\s:\s([^\^]+)\^([^\^]+)/g
```

Inside PHP:

```
$str = "1 : Lastname^Firstname^MiddleName^Prefix^Suffix 2 : Lastname^Firstname^^^ 3 : Lastname^Firstname";

//the 'g' flag doesn't exist in PHP, instead use preg_match_all function:
$regex = "/\d+\s:\s([^\^]+)\^([^\^]+)/"; 

// PHP >= 5.2.2
preg_match_all($regex, $str, $matches);

print_r($matches[1]); //Last names
print_r($matches[2]); //First names
```

Answer (score 0):

Cannot test it right now, but it should be something like the following:

```
(\w+)\^(\w+)(\^\w+){0,3}
```

Group 1 and 2 return lastname and firstname respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following regex...

Last Name: `^\w*(?=\^)`

First Name: `(<=^\w*\^)\w*(?=\^*)`

Good Luck!